# Freebase: Hosting a Freebase API on Amazon

Tags: semantic-web, freebase

The [tutorial](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Working_with_Freebase_data_on_Amazon_AWS) talks about setting up a Freebase instance on Amazon. When I follow this process I end up having an instance that has Freebase data via a EBS attached to it. Can anyone help me through a process using which I can use the underlying data to create a Freebase API.

I assume that just like one can host Dbpedia on Virtuoso where Dbpedia is exposed as API there should be (Assumption) a way to host Freebase. I have failed to find a resource which talks about the same. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Ankit S

Answer (score 3):

Virtuoso is a piece of software.  Freebase is an open source database/data source, but the software which provides the Freebase API isn't open source (or available), so there's no way to host a Freebase API on Amazon without reimplementing the software.

If you want to use the data, the most straightforward way is probably to use it using a graph database like Cayley or Neo4J or an RDF database like Virtuoso and then query it using either SPARQL or a graph DB API.

Answer (score 2):

I put freebase into Solr/Lucene. It seems to work particularly well. The object field was cloned and tokenized for good text searches. The other hierarchy was preserved for exact matches. Put it into 8 cores.

I think there are only 5 types of triple to parse.

```
# <><><///...>.
# <><><///#>.
# <><>"".
# <><>""@x.
# <><>""^^<>.
```

Parse to the quotes from both sides so you know what you're dealing with. I limited the triples to 32K bytes. I kick the slag into a gz file to look at, and re-add if there's a format change. I check that it's formatted correctly. It took 5 days to load. Solr uses Jetty and it's particular; the data must be escaped properly, no &, there are about 20 triples that have ascii 0, 11, .., which you may want to push into the slag pile. It went pretty well thanks to Solr project, which is excellent.

A note on decompressing it. I divided it into 100 files. Java is broken for this, so is Ruby. You can use linux gunzip -c | pipe to your script. You may not be able to contain it inside one ruby or java program. Didn't find the reason for this. On the host khugepaged = bad. 200G of ram, it went away for 5 minutes using 100% of 16 CPUs.